# How to add an DataBound Event Handler to a ListView in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using an `ObservableCollection<T>` bound to a `ListView` on xamarin forms. And would like to make an empty list verification and show a `label`.

I need to add an "EventHandler" to the list view when data is added, removed or is binded for the first time.

the Add and Remove events can be obtained from the `ObservableCollection` List. but there is no event for when the list is bounded for the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about that?

```
<ListView.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FilteredTasks, Converter={StaticResource EmptyCollectionToBoolConverter}}" Value="true" TargetType="ListView">
        <Setter Property="Header">
            <Label Text="Ooops, there is nothing there."/>
        </Setter>
    </DataTrigger>
</ListView.Triggers>
```

and the converter is:

```
public class EmptyCollectionToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is ICollection collection)
        {
            return collection.Count == 0;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no a simpler solution like `onDataBound`Event ?